# How to save MS bot state data and conversations ?

Tags: node.js, botframework, bots, azure-cosmosdb, cortana

I am using node js and Microsoft Bot builder sdk to write a BOT. Currently, I am saving everything in data bags (conversationData, userData etc) and using CosmosDb to store the state. I followed this article to configure CosmosDB & made changes as per nodejs.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/bot-conversation-history-with-azure-cosmos-db/

There are few concerns with this approach,

1. conversationData bag is cleared when we call endConversation() in dialog. Thats expected by sdk design but we would like to persist this data for multiple conversation flows with same user (same conversation id.) Now, json cosmosDb in db gets replaced with new keys on conversationData when user start new intent.
   Ex: schedule a meeting with {name} for {day} at {place}.
   we save conversationData.name , conversationData.day , and conversationData. place.
   same user starts over schedule a meeting with {name2} for {day2} at {place2}.
   documentDb entry gets replaced with conversationData.name1 , conversationData.day2 , and conversationData. place2

Ideally, we would like to keep everything.

Is there a better way to save chat history & conversationData, userData
databags in MS BOT ?.

Answer (score 1):

All storage implementations just write getData and saveData, they internally have a key:value store where key is typically userId + conversationId, but you can make it whatever you want as long as you can reliably derive it from the arguments passed to `getData` and `setData`.

Looking at a sample in redis https://github.com/suttna/botbuilder-redis-storage - https://github.com/suttna/botbuilder-redis-storage/blob/master/src/storage.ts for an example storage implementation that's pretty easy to follow.

You would use a custom implementation like this

```
// Create new storage with redis client
var storage = new YourStorage()

// this is just here for the sake of initializing a `bot`
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector()
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector)

// Configure bot to use YourStorage
bot.set('storage', storage)

bot.set('persistConversationData', true);
```

`storage` is just an object that implements

```
public saveData(context: IBotStorageContext, data: IBotStorageData, callback?: (err: Error) => void)

public getData(context: IBotStorageContext, callback: (err: Error, data: IBotStorageData) => void)
```

I totally just copied those signatures from the linked redis module, but they are the same in the BotBuilder source for the default storage - https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/5cf71c742f27d89e9dbc4076f850122bd6edac11/Node/calling/src/storage/BotStorage.ts

The samples are in typescript. If you are unfamiliar, ignore the bit right after `:` which indicates the type of a thing.

Comment: I'm confused. Did you mean overriding getData & setData methods of CosmosDb so I can alter the behavior of conversation Data bag which is cleared once conversation ends. My goal is keep everything in DB which is on session object.
session.userData.{}

Comment: yes, or just roll your own storage implementation. They aren't that much code to write, just do what that redis implementation does except save to cosmos or whatever your storage engine is. session.userData is populated by botbuilder using these methods on whatever storage you gave it.

Comment: `session.userData` will have a searchable key of ``"${userId};userData"``and is not cleared when `session.endConversation()` is called. And as Catalyst mentions you could change the storage implementation. It sounds like you want to generate a new key that is something like [`userId;conversationId;currentDate`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/core/src/storage/BotStorage.ts#L99)

Comment: @StevenG
I appreciate the feedback but I think I am not following how would I change the storage implementation. Did you mean override the methods  saveData() and getData(). 

here is what I have done so far with cosmos based on Catalyst's comment. 
---
var cosmosStorage = setCosmosStorage();
function setCosmosStorage() {
    var docDbClient = new azure.DocumentDbClient({
     //connection details.
    });
    var cosmosStorage = new azure.AzureBotStorage({ gzipData: false }, docDbClient);
    return cosmosStorage;
}

Comment: //Middleware for logging(RJ-db,logging)
`bot.use({
    receive: function (event, next) {
        logUserConversation("User", event, event.user.id);
        next();
    },
    send: function (event, next) {
        logUserConversation("Bot", event, event.address.user.id);
        next();
    }
});
var chatHistory = []
const logUserConversation = (identifier, event, id) => {
    chatHistory[event.address.conversation.id] += (event.text);
    console.log('*** BOT/User Message: ' + event.text);
};`

Comment: Sorry for the code formatting.
But here is whats happening. 
conversationData bag is cleared when endConversation() is called in BOT.  So I'am not able to persist the data from conversationData.

Now, in order to store chatHistory I used BOT Middleware for logging each message from BOT and user. & but then I don't know how to save that on cosmosDb.